# New ceiling fan with remote wiring help

Tags: ceiling-fan

[image]

I need help with the wiring of a new ceiling fan.  The previous ceiling fan was wired to two switches on the wall, one to control the light and one to control the fan.  The new harbor breeze fan one has a remote with it.  I have two sets of wires coming out of my ceiling, the ceiling fan has one black wire and one white wire.  How do I connect these wires to make everything work again?

Comment: No instruction sheet with the fan?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44925/how-should-i-wire-a-ceiling-fan-remote-where-two-switches-are-used-to-control- check this link

Comment: Instruction sheet doesn’t address the two sets of wires and switches.

Comment: How much do you want the remote here?  Is taking the fan back and getting a different one an option?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I wire a ceiling fan remote where two switches are used to control the fixture?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44925/how-should-i-wire-a-ceiling-fan-remote-where-two-switches-are-used-to-control-th)

Comment: Do you want to control it with the remote? Or the switches?  Can't have both.