# Hunter Ceiling Fan with Remote to dual switch on wall - how to wire?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

Long story short, all was working per my question below as installed by a contractor(I'm 99% sure) - until it came loose from the ceiling and i quickly undid all of the wiring (lesson learned - quick picture first).

I've read the other posts for this same issue and what I can't tell is if it's possible to have
1) Top switch for light on/off AND turn light on/off from remote
2) Bottom switch for fan on/off AND turn off, control speed from remote

Currently I got this far...
Dual switch on wall: 
Top turns light on/off, If top switch is on, I can **NOT** use remote to turn off light (This is where I need help)
Bottom turns fan on/off, I **CAN** control fan speed and turn off AND i noticed I can also control the light - but only if top switch is off and bottom is on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/44925/46271  this may help

Comment: Thanks Kris. I read this from Tester101 as either or, not both. Reading notes under diagrams I found "Now when one switch is on, the **remote will control the light. The other switch will turn the fan on and off**." and "This way the **remote module will control the fan (when the switch is in the ON position), and the other switch will control the light.**"

Comment: How many wires are there between the wallbox and the fan box, and is pulling new cable an option? (Or is this one of those awesome things we call "conduit jobs" where the wires are in conduit, making adding more easy?)

Comment: Also, does power come in at the switch or at the fan?