# Where to connect the red wire from ceiling to a Ceiling fan with remote?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, remote-control

What to do with red wire from ceiling/supply when hooking up ceiling fan with attached light and remote?

First time- I put the black wire from receiver output side (this side has wires that are black, white and blue) and black from fan to the red wire from ceiling supply in one wire nut.
Remote worked for fan temporarily. I turned off breaker and then stopped working for fan. The remote still worked to control the lights on fan.

Second time, I capped the red wire from the ceiling. Now, on the remote fan buttons(low, med, high speed) won’t turn on. However, the variable breeze button that’s for the fan makes the the lights flicker on the ceiling fan.

I have not checked yet to see if need to cap the red wire in the wall switch.

Any ideas what I did wrong or what to do?[image]

Comment: A picture of the ceiling box showing all the wires   May help       Also the wall switch box     Was there a separate switch for light and fan  on previous set up?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the fan and switch boxes involved please?

Comment: Meanwhile have a look at this possible[ duplicate question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/44925/46271) and it’s answers.

Comment: The remote allows independent control of light and fan with only one hot wire input to the receiver. If you have two input hots available, the simplest thing is to use only one, e.g., the black, and cap off the red input.

Comment: To Kris first comment : From ceiling supply is white, black, red and ground wires.  

No fan installed in home previously. New home. 

has 2 gang box switches on wall. One dedicated switch for the for the 4 can receptacles and the right switch could be used to control fan.

Comment: To Kris Second comment:  Yes looked at that post to do the first installation but problem with that post there are two switches. I only have one switch to control the fan.

Comment: Jim Stewart- the configuration has the red cap off at the ceiling now and not working anymore. It did previously work with the black from receiver, red wire from ceiling and black fan wire together in one nut. Then turned off breaker for something else and now no power to the fan motor.

Comment: Are red and black wires in the same cable with only one white neutral which they share? Are the red and white hots on (1) the same 1-pole breaker or (2) two different 1-pole breakers or (3) on the two sides of a 2-pole breaker?

Comment: Jim- Yes, the ceiling just has one set of wires that has red white black and ground.  This is a new house, one switch for recess lights and then the one switch- I am trying to use for the fan. The two switches are located together in a 2 gang box. 

Oops I said 4 can receptacles meant recess lighting, in an earlier comment sorry.

Comment: @user3537618 -- can you post photos of the inside of the switch box involved please?

Comment: Three Phase El- are you asking me to check if there is a red wire in the switch box? If so do I cap it too since will be capping the red at the ceiling supply? Thanks!  Don’t have a pic on me unfortunately.